# Combining variations of a product

Tags: product, configurable-product, product-attribute, product-list, attribute-set

I'm trying to create variation in sizes for a single product of different color. So I want to give the customer the option to choose the size ONLY. Color of the product will be defined by me. For example, suppose I'm selling a jacket which is available in Blue, Grey and Black color. Sizes are usual, viz: M, L, XL, XXL.

So I will list the product like this:

**Men's ABC Jacket- Blue**

Sizes: *M, L, XL, XXL*

**Men's ABC Jacket- Black**

Sizes: *M, L, XL, XXL*

And so on...

Now, if I do this using the attribute sets generator feature then I will end up creating single listing for each variation in Size. Therefore, the total number of listings would be: 3x4=12

12 listing for a single product? Does that really sound fair enough? Since I'm an amateur in the world of Programing and Magento, I dunno if there's any alternative of incorporating different sizes in One single listing. (Prestashop offers this features and it works seamlessly)

Lemme make it more clear. I want the sizes to be combined in a listing for a specific color. Like, If the listing is for BLACK color jacket, then the most a customer has to do is to just choose the Size. Nothing else! I don't want my customers to surf across my website just to find the listing for their size. Right now after following the instructions on this blog: http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/

I ended up creating 4 different listing for same color but different sizes.
[image: screenshot]

So as you can see in the screenshot of the products page of my website, there are 4 different listing for 4 different sizes but same color. Can anyone please tell me how can I create a single listing for "Light Grey" color jacket and add variable sizes into so that customer can just choose the size.

Please help me. I'll buy you a beer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use configurable products.
With that you will create simple products that are the sizes, and set them to not be visible in catalog.

You then attach these to the main configurable product.

I suggest you install magento test site with the demo products, which will give you all the examples you need

Comment: Thanks a lot @ProxiBlue Although your description was informative enough, this video on YouTube worked like a charm for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X72qnYylQdU